# Is there a standard function for this?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

There is probably built-in function or a better and faster way to do this in Mathematica

```
func[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ f @@@ Transpose[{Most[l], Rest[l]}]
```

which can be used to do things like this

```
l = {a, b, c, d}
func[l, Plus, (#1 - #2)^2 &]
```

I don't know the proper name for this kind of function. Something in a fold-zip genre.

**UPDATE**
Lot's of solutions. Thanks to everyone.

Using

```
Partition[l, 2, 1]
```

instead of

```
Transpose[{Most[l], Rest[l]}]
```

definitely makes it clearer.

I've tried to run timings on the functions, but I get strange results:

```
func1[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ f @@@ Transpose[{Most[l], Rest[l]}]
func2[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ f @@@ Partition[l, 2, 1]
func3[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ ListConvolve[{1, 1}, l, {-1, 1}, {}, Times, f]
func4[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ Thread[f[Most@l, Rest@l]]
func5[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ f /@ Partition[l, 2, 1]
func6[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ Thread[f[Most[l], Rest[l]]]
func7[l_, f_, g_] := Inner[f, Sequence @@ Partition[l, Length[l] - 1, 1], g]
func8[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ MapThread[f, Partition[l, Length[l] - 1, 1]]
functions = {func1, func2, func3, func4, func5, func6, func7, func8}

input = Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 1000000}];
inputs = Table[Take[input, i*100000], {i, 1, 10}];

Table[
  If[i == j == 0, "",
  If[j == 0, functions[[i]],
  If[i == 0, Length[inputs[[j]]],
    Timing[functions[[i]][inputs[[j]]]][[1]]]]], 
    {i, 0, Length[functions]}, {j, 0, Length[inputs]}] // Transpose // TableForm
```

Comment: Just an OT comment. To generate your big list `input` it's faster to use `Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1000000}]` or `Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] &, 1000000]` than `ToExpression[...]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want something that exactly duplicates the functionality of your `func`, the only prettyfication I can think of is replacing `Transpose[Most[l],Rest[l]]` with `Partition`:

```
func2[l_,g_,f_]:=g@@f@@@Partition[l,2,1]
```

If you really want something "built in", you could hack on some `ListConvolve` for kicks

```
func3[l_,g_,f_]:=g@@ListConvolve[{1,1},l,{-1,1},{},Times,f]
```

Checking that all these work:

```
Through[{func,func2,func3}[l,Plus,(#1-#2)^2&]]
Out[19]= {(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2,(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2,(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2}
```

Finally, if this is the answer you are looking for, I would suggest computing it by `Total[Differences[l]^2]`

```
Out[14]= (-a+b)^2+(-b+c)^2+(-c+d)^2
```

Comment: A nice set of options. `Differences` is a special application of `ListConvolve`, so it does not need to duplicate the list like the `Partition` and `Most, Rest` do. Thus it should be more memory efficient. It's also about 1/3 faster than my solution.

Comment: @Simon But the OP pointed to general functions of the contiguous list elements.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you see something like `f@@@Transpose[{args}]` you should think of `Thread[]`. This was discussed in [The semantics of Mathematica's Thread function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250125/421225).

So the best I could do was

```
func[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ Thread[f[Most[l], Rest[l]]]
```

but the `Most[l], Rest[l]` construction still seems ugly and inefficient. There is probably a more efficient way to do it - but maybe this is as compact as it can get in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `Thread` -- although I actually like `@@@`. As for the `Transpose[Most,Rest]` the thing to do is to use `Partition`.

Comment: @Janus Partition[l, Length@l - 1, 1] = {Most, Rest}

Comment: @Janus `Partition` still duplicates the initial data, which is what I was primarily concerned about. Your solution with `ListConvolve` or `Differences` gets around that problem.

Comment: @belisarius Such a cut-throat competition here! Normally I don't see questions until they appear in my RSS feed. This time I was online and you still beat me by 1 minute!

Comment: @Simon Hush! Max emailed the question beforehand!

Comment: I got to the party to late.  Nothing for days, and two in a matter of hours.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent to (not saying it's better):

```
      func[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ Thread[f[Most@l, Rest@l]]
```

Or almost

```
      func[l_, g_, f_] := g @@ f /@ Partition[l, 2, 1]
```

But this last one needs

```
      func[l, Plus, (#[[1]] + #[[2]])^2 &]
```

Which is clearly inferior

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer but a suggestion for a better timing routine. This

```
 timeAvg[func_] := Module[{
    x = 0, y = 0, timeLimit = 0.1, p, q, 
    iterTimes = Power[10, Range[0, 10]]},
   Catch[
     If[(x = First[Timing[(y++; Do[func, {#}]);]]) > timeLimit,
        Throw[{x, y}]
        ] & /@ iterTimes
     ] /. {p_, q_} :> p/iterTimes[[q]]
   ];
Attributes[timeAvg] = {HoldAll};
```

will calculate an average run time quite quickly, e.g.,

```
timeAvg@func1[l, Plus, (#1 - #2)^2 &]
```

Trying out different lengths for `l` gives the following result
[image: Timing]
where N is the number of elements in `l`. `Thread[]` is the clear winner.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's just an generalized inner product (generalized dot product), modulo the `Transpose`/`Most`/`Rest` bit, so you could also just use [`Inner`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inner.html):

```
func[lis_, f_, g_] := Inner[f, Sequence@@Partition[list, Length[lis]-1, 1], g]

In[90]:= func[l,Plus,(#-#2)^2&]
Out[90]= (a - b)^2 + (b - c)^2 + (c - d)^2
```

There's also [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html), which I mention for completeness:

```
func2[lis_, g_, f_] := g @@ MapThread[f, Partition[lis, Length[lis]-1, 1]]

In[94]:= func2[l, Plus, (# - #2)^2 &]
Out[94]= (a - b)^2 + (b - c)^2 + (c - d)^2
```

If you're always making differences out of the list, `Differences` or `ListConvolve` could be faster, as others have mentioned.

Like Perl, [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) in 
Mathematica too, as all the answers to your question show!